# Apache on linux with two real certificates (.com and .co.uk)

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

I can only configure one. when I try to configure the other I get httpd error with bad syntax.
any one know how to configure 2 certificates in apache?
this is what I have:

```
# ssl

LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443

AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLMutex default
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName  company ip address
  ServerAlias *.company wild card certificate 
  DocumentRoot /live/html

  ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log             
  TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
 LogLevel warn

  RewriteEngine on     
  RewriteOptions Inherit

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2               
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

###  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/pki/company.co.uk.crt
###  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/pki/server.key
###  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/pki/intermediate.crt

SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/pki/USA/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/pki/USA/server.key
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/pki/USA/intermediate.crt

  <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Files>
 <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Directory>

 SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
          nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
           downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

  CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
           "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What problem is this the solution to? (Also, this won't work if both services are using the same IP address. [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) is not production-ready yet.)

Comment: The production-readiness of SNI will coincide with the eradication of Windows XP, because SNI works fine on any reasonably recent version of Firefox/Safari/Chrome as well as IE7 and up on Vista or better. It just doesn't work in IE6 or in any version of IE on XP.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Linux and Apache. I'm also using GEO DNS and I want my europe customers who are not using co.uk to be able to reach me with .com and not go to my USA servers. this is the reason I need 2 certificates on my Europe servers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an IP/certificate. You can only use one certificate per IP. So instead of *:443 in your vhost you should use an IP.